# The étale cohomology of the formal punctured disc over an affine scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Forgive the horrible formatting. I'm typing this on a phone on account of having a broken laptop.

I'd like to understand the étale cohomology (with say Z/l coefficients) of schemes of the form spec(A((z))), for A an algebra over the complexes. Feel free to add appropriate conditions on A. In particular does a version of the Künneth theorem hold?